# Add Multiple Domains to one single Web App via code

Tags: php, azure, url, url-rewriting

I have a PHP App running on my Azure. I want my customers to be able to use my application on their own domains. Is it possible to add multiple domains to one single web application? Is there an API or something to add domains to a web app programatically?

I have a web.config file that looks like below but it doesn't redirect.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite domain requests" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.cemiltokatli.com/url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to move your web app to the shared/standard mode and:

1) configure url rewriting (like described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cschotte/2013/05/30/hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-azure-website/))

2) configure multiple domain names using **Site.HostNames** property. That property can be used for setting additional domains. Unfortunately, i have no PHP code snippet, but working C# code is below (implemented using [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/Models/WebSiteUpdateParameters.cs)). And, again, unfortunately, but it looks like the official [Azure PHP SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php) does not provide the same functionality. The way here would be to write a REST API wrapper using, for example, the snippet below as a reference. If there is no possibility from your side to execute the code and catch the request, i can do that a little later, if that will help.

```
public const string base64EncodedCertificate = "ManagementCertificateValueFromPublishSettingsFile";
public const string subscriptionId = "AzureSubscriptionId";

static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials()
{
    return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate)));
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebSiteManagementClient client = new WebSiteManagementClient(getCredentials());

    WebSpacesListResponse n = client.WebSpaces.List();
    n.Select(p =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("webspace {0}", p.Name);
        WebSpacesListWebSitesResponse websitesInWebspace = client.WebSpaces.ListWebSites(p.Name,
              new WebSiteListParameters()
              {
              });
        websitesInWebspace.Select(o =>
        {
            Console.Write(o.Name);     

            return o;
        }).ToArray();
        return p;
    }).ToArray();

    Console.ReadLine();
    var configuration = client.WebSites.Get("WebSpaceName", "WebSiteName", new WebSiteGetParameters());

    configuration.WebSite.HostNames.Add("new domain");
    var resp = client.WebSites.Update("WebSpaceName", "WebSiteName", new WebSiteUpdateParameters() { HostNames = configuration.WebSite.HostNames });
    Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do not misunderstand your question, you want to manage multiple domains directing to your one Azure Web App application. E.G. manage `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` to the same `yourapp.azurewebsites.net`.

You can let your customer to add a CName of your azure application on his own DNS manage server. 
[image]

Then, scale up your application's app service plan to at leaset **share** tier. And in **CONFIGURE** tab of your Azure Web App's portal page, under *domain names* section, add yor custom's domain into the list. E.G.
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.